# How to use gpt4 in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, openai-api

I am trying to make a simple chat app with gpt4 but i got stuck, and gpt itself cant help me :D

So, i tried few end points i saw online, but nothing works. I get allways "The API response is missing or empty.". What is missing here?

My code:

```
    Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Text
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class Form1
    Private apiKey As String = "YOUR_API_KEY"
    Private endpointUrl As String = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/gpt-4-8k/completions"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim prompt As String = TextBox1.Text

        Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & apiKey)

        Dim requestData As New JObject()
        requestData("prompt") = prompt
        requestData("max_tokens") = 50 ' Променете това според вашите нужди

        Dim httpContent As HttpContent = New StringContent(requestData.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        Dim response = client.PostAsync(endpointUrl, httpContent).Result

        Dim jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result

        ' Parsing the response
        Dim responseObject = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse)
        Dim choices As JArray = responseObject("choices")

        If choices IsNot Nothing AndAlso choices.Count > 0 Then
            Dim reply As String = choices(0)("text").ToString()
            TextBox2.Text = reply
        Else
            TextBox2.Text = "The API response is missing or empty."
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Check the response, specifically the StatusCode.  Bet you're not getting a 200 response.  Via Debugger, check the response object as well, there might be info in there as to what the issue is

Comment: And probably a good place to start, use a tool such as postman to figure the mechanics of the requests, then replicate to cod

Comment: It's probably a good idea to make use of a .NET library that performs the authentication / queries / completions -- Unrelated: you should REALLY learn to await asynchronous calls

Answer (score 1):

Try this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMYzGJDakgY

```
    public string SendMsg(string sQuestion)
    {

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
            System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | 
            System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
            System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
            System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        
        string apiEndpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions";
        var request = WebRequest.Create(apiEndpoint);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + OPENAI_API_KEY);

        int iMaxTokens = int.Parse( txtMaxTokens.Text); // 2048

        double dTemperature = double.Parse(txtTemperature.Text); // 0.5
        if (dTemperature < 0d | dTemperature > 1d)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Randomness has to be between 0 and 1 with higher values resulting in more random text");
            return "";
        }

        string sUserId = txtUserID.Text; // 1
        string sModel = cbModel.Text; // text-davinci-002, text-davinci-003

        string data = "{";
        data += " \"model\":\"" + sModel + "\",";
        data += " \"prompt\": \"" + PadQuotes(sQuestion) + "\",";
        data += " \"max_tokens\": " + iMaxTokens + ",";
        data += " \"user\": \"" + sUserId + "\", ";
        data += " \"temperature\": " + dTemperature + ", ";
        data += " \"frequency_penalty\": 0.0" + ", "; // Number between -2.0 and 2.0  Positive value decrease the model's likelihood to repeat the same line verbatim.
        data += " \"presence_penalty\": 0.0" + ", "; // Number between -2.0 and 2.0. Positive values increase the model's likelihood to talk about new topics.
        data += " \"stop\": [\"#\", \";\"]"; // Up to 4 sequences where the API will stop generating further tokens. The returned text will not contain the stop sequence.
        data += "}";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(data);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string sJson = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        // Return sJson

        var oJavaScriptSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, object> oJson = (Dictionary<string, object>) oJavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject(sJson);
        Object[] oChoices = (Object[])oJson["choices"];
        Dictionary<string, object> oChoice = (Dictionary<string, object>) oChoices[0];
        string sResponse = (string) oChoice["text"];

        return sResponse;

    }
```